# How can I subset a large array based on a list?

Tags: arrays, r, loops, apply

I have a `large array of 150000 elements`

```
structure(c(0.297737591051841, 0.29315072190034, 0.300524437089258, 
0.297581868890772, 0.29315252160195, 0.30052371791622, 0.297447088491222, 
0.293154289987493, 0.300522998984405, 0.297331962830338), .Dim = 10L)
```

And I have a list of indices:

```
List of 3

int[1:8784(1d)] 1 4 7 10 13
num[1:8784(1d)] 2 5 8 11 14
num[1:8784(1d)] 3 6 9 12 15
```

How can I subset the array based on the list?

So far, I am doing this one by one by using the indices before I made the list:

```
data.frame(array[list1], array[list2], array[list3])
```

What's the smarter way to do this?

Comment: @akrun Done. It's a 1d array.

Comment: @akrun I think it's concatenating the numbers?

Comment: I guess you have a single list with 3 vectors as indices, right?

Comment: yes. But I think your answer works. Let me check.

Comment: Try the solution I posted below because earlier I was thinking of 3D array

Comment: Perfect. That worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do

```
as.data.frame(sapply(lst, function(x) ar1[x]))
```

---

Or with `Map`

```
data.frame(Map(`[`, list(ar1), lst))
```

Edit: changed from `mapply` to `Map` (based on @thelatemail's comments)